# Why don't the values of Log[10, x] on the y-axis of a log plot of a list x-values?

Tags: plotting, functions, logarithmic-scale

I evaluated `Log[10, {list}]`, where `list` is a list of reals. I also evaluated `LogListPlot[{list}]`. When I compare them, they don't seem to match up.

Can anyone help clear up what `Log[10, {list}]` and `LogListPlot[{list}]` is doing differently?

Comment: You should provide a self-contained example of what you are experiencing.  In version 10.1 these produce the same plot other than the Y scale: `SeedRandom[0]; a = RandomReal[100, 50];` then `ListPlot[Log[10, a]]` and `ListLogPlot[a]`

Comment: list = {0.0000861804, 0.0000863112, 0.0000896232} , Log[10,{list}] = {-4.06459, -4.06393, -4.04758} and when I use ListLogPlot[{list}]  I don't see any negative values. I'm really not sure what it is doing.

Comment: You should not see any negative values in the plot as `{0.0000861804, 0.0000863112, 0.0000896232}` does not contain any negative values.  The positions of the points are scaled logarithmically but the Y-axis labels match the original values in the list, not the scaled ones.

Comment: thank you, Im going to read up on what you just said and try to understand it a little more.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware that `ListLogPlot`

- plots `Log[x]`, not `Log[10, x]` as the ordinates (y values) of the plot  (this only introduces a scaling difference)
- labels the y-axis so the plotted points get labeled with `x` values, not `Log[x]` values
- by default uses the indices of the elements in `list` to label the x-axis (you can override the default behavior)

You may find the following variation of `ListLogPlot` helps you to understand these points.

```
With[{xvals = Range[Length[list]]},
  ListLogPlot[Callout[#, #] & /@ list,
    Ticks -> {xvals, Automatic},
    Prolog -> 
      {Red, AbsolutePointSize[10], Point[Transpose[{xvals, Log[list]}]]}]]
```

[image: plot]

Note that to plot the red points behind the data points, I had to specify their y-coordinate as `Log[x]`, not `Log[10, x]` to get them in the right place. This confirms that `ListLogPlot` is plotting `Log[x]`, not `Log[10, x]`

Comment: Thank you, this definitely helped.